# How remove outliers from 2 dimension array in python

Tags: python, outliers

I don't know how remove outliers from 2-dimensional data.
For example I have:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 8, 2, 10])

plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("value")

plt.scatter(x, y, color = "g", marker = "o")
```

[image]

As You see outliers are points in 5-th and 8-th X positions.

How to find them and remove them in python?

**IMPORTANT**

This is only an **example** data. If You want to help me, please provide a general answer on how to handle these kinds of problems. IQR does not seem to be solution for that problem.

Comment: Is the data always going to be a linear increasing line like this, or will be decreasing as well?

Comment: You can measure the slope across different points and threshold them based on the average

Comment: This kind of outlier-detection problem is tailor-made for [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus). It's easy and simple to implement, and a pseudo-code example is given in that wikipedia article. Give it a shot.

Comment: What is your algorithm for deciding what is and isn't an outlier? What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what was wrong with your attempts? If you're looking for a mathematical algorithm or staistical test for general outlier detection, there are math and stats stack exchange site. This site asks for a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

This is usually done by calculating the Standard Deviation for each point in a dataset and then choosing a deviation value beyond which you'll toss out the datapoint with that value.

You're using `numpy`.  I don't know for sure, but I expect that the `numpy` module includes the ability to calculate Standard Deviation on a set of data point.  [Check this out.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html)

Comment: It's not that simple when the model is a 2D line. Consider the points at the very top right and bottom left of the example image - those points will have the largest deviation from the centroid, yet they're actually part of the inlier set.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was thinking of the deviation of the distances of each point from the line.  You'd first fit a line to the points.  Then calculate the distances of each point to the line, and use them to determine which points to throw out, then fit a new line to the remaining points.  It's been quite a while since I did this.

Comment: You can’t accurately fit a line to the points until you’ve rejected the outliers in the first place.